# How to check if a string is an operator (+, -, *, /, ==, ===) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a cheap way of distinguishing operators in JavaScript? (*other than `eval()`*)

*i.e.* Given an operator `'+'` in string form, how can you know that it's **+** ?

As `typeof '+'` - will return `string`

And `isNaN('+')` - will return `true`, but so will `isNaN('-')`

The context for this question is this LeetCode challenge: https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation (I'm not looking for a solution to the challenge, I'm just curious)

Comment: Use Regex for this.

Comment: The same way you would determine this for any other candidate string?  `indexOf()`, maybe?

Comment: Why can't you just do `someStringifiedOperator === '+'`?

Comment: What do you really want to achive? Checking the operators is only part of a larger task, and that task is interesting to know about.

Comment: `if (v === '===')` *that's strict equality*

Comment: @RingØ `if (v === '===')` will mean that I have to do it for every single one `('+', '-', '*', '/', '<', '>', '!=', '!==', '==', '===')`, I was just wandering if there is a easier method that I overlooked.

Comment: Try a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Writing_a_regular_expression_pattern)

Comment: @aguilar Won't the regex just tell me that it **is** a match, instead of which one it is?

Comment: In this case, giving semantics to a raw string, there are two (similar) ways I know, one is `eval()`, another one is building a function thanks to the constructor. Meaning build a string that does the operation (like `eval (x + op + y)` op being the operator string). Nothing wrong with a `switch` for that kind of problem.

Comment: The *cheapest* way is using a simple `switch` statement. A more expensive way is to use an actual JavaScript parser and walk the AST (assuming you can generate valid JavaScript code). However, I fail to see how you would use `eval` to find out what operator you are given.

Comment: Put all the known operators in an array and use [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

Comment: @grigio Whenever you ask a question on Stack Overflow, you should always describe the context in which your code will work. That makes it much easier to give _appropriate_ answers.

Comment: The problem you're solving involves four operators, and presumably your code has to recognize them and handle them accordingly, so why not just use equality to check them?

Answer (score 4):

You can go by ASCII code. the way we do it in `c/c++` . for example `+` ascii code equavalant is 45 . now you can check

```
if(45 === 'str[i]]'.charCodeAt(0))
{
  // do something
}
```

I hope this help, if not , then feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all the operators you suspect the string could be:

```
var isOperator = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '==', '==='].some((item) => {
    return item === inputStr;    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be storing your operators in an array, then use the array method [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if an element is an operator:

```js
const operators =  ['+', '-', '*', '/', '==', '==='];

const isOperator = (e) => operators.includes(e);

let exp = ["10", "6", "9", "3", "+", "-11", "*", "/", "*", "17", "+", "5", "+"];

console.log(exp.map(x => isOperator(x) ? x + " is operator" : x));
```